# Errors importing JS project into eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am importing a JS library into Eclipse but I am getting hundreds of errors like this one for the code below. Any ideas?

**Javascript:**

```
switch (authVerb) {
      case 'basic':
        self.auth(self._user, self._pass, true)
        redirectTo = self.uri
        break

      case 'bearer':
        self.auth(null, null, true, self._bearer)
        redirectTo = self.uri
        break
}
```

**Error:**

> break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch

Answer (score 1):

Check your code against JSLint (http://www.jslint.com/). After you've solved every "error" Eclipse should be able to import the code without worrying about anything.

```
switch (authVerb) {
      case 'basic':
        self.auth(self._user, self._pass, true);
        redirectTo = self.uri;
        break;

      case 'bearer':
        self.auth(null, null, true, self._bearer);
        redirectTo = self.uri;
        break;
}
```